# GCC / Linux: adding a static library to a .so?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

I've a program that implements a plugin system by dynamically loading a function from some plugin_name.so (as usual).

But in turn I've a static "helper" library (lets call it helper.a) whose functions are used both from the main program and the main function in the plugin. They don't have to inter-operate in any way, they are just helper functions for text manipulation and such.

This program, once started, cannot be reloaded or restarted, that's why I'm expecting to have new "helper" functionality from the plugin, not from the main program.

So my questin is.. is it possible to force this "plugin function code" in the .so to use (statically link against?) a different (perhaps newer) version of "helper" than the main program?

How could this be done? perhaps by statically linking or otherwise adding helper.a to plugin_name.so?

Comment: I'd like to add that I don't want or expect to use the new helper library from the main program.. I'd just want to link each new plugin with a newer/better helper library.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use dynamic linking for the helper function?

Comment: once started, the main program cannot stop execution, even to reload a newer helper.so.. and the program need just very basic helper functionality since it's just a placeholder for plugins. so I prefer to compile the whole plugin again if I have a new/improved or extended helper library. I think it is more practical to distribute a single .so (the plugin) than two .so (plugin and the most up-to-date helper that plugin uses)

Comment: So you need to be able to update the library code which the plugin or plugins use, without restarting the main process?

Comment: that's correct, with the added complexity that there could be dozens of plugins running concurrently as threads, each one with their own version of the helper library (the newer the plugin, chances are the newer is the library) -and- the main program also has the helper library built-in for some very simple actions, the latest version available at its compilation time (I really don't care to update this while it works ok). there could be, also, other libraries -using the functionality from helper- that could be linked to each plugin.. perhaps some plugins will also share those libs..

Comment: the whole point is not to touch the main program but add any functionality via plugins and their updated libraries/functionality without closing threads or cancel the main program. that's basically the idea.

to get a better idea, the real name for "helper.a" in the project is "core", and it's a collection of classes for storing data, http requests, regex matching, etc. that's why I need it on the main program but I don't care to update if it works ok..

Comment: I don't know enough about PIC to write this in an answer, but doesn't an `.so` need to be compiled with `-fPIC` and wouldn't mixing non-PIC and PIC code cause problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nick Meyer's answer is correct on Windows and AIX, but is unlikely to be correct on every other UNIX platform by default.

On most UNIX platforms, the runtime loader maintains a *single* name space for all symbols, so if you define `foo_helper` in `a.out`, and also in `plugin.so`, and then call `foo_helper` from either, the first definition visible to the runtime loader (usually that from `a.out`) is used by default for *both* calls.

In addition, the picture is complicated by the fact that `foo_helper` may not be exported from `a.out` (and thus may be invisible to runtime loader), unless you use `-rdynamic` flag, or some *other* shared library references it. In other words, things may *appear* to work as Nick described them, then you add a shared library to the `a.out` link line, and they don't work that way anymore.

On ELF platforms (such as Linux), you have great control over symbol visibility and binding. See description of `-fvisibility=hidden` and `-rdynamic` in `GCC` man page, and also `-Bsymbolic` in linker man page.

Most other UNIX platforms have some way to control symbol bindings as well, but this is necessarily platform-specific.

Answer (score 1):

If your main program and dynamic library both statically link to helper.a, then you shouldn't need to worry about mixing versions of helper.a (as long as you don't do things like pass pointers allocated in helper.a between the .exe and .so boundaries).

The code required from the helper.a is inserted to the actual binary when you link against it.  So when you call into helper.a from the .exe, you will be executing code from the code segment of your executable image, and when you call into helper.a from the .so, you will be executing code from the portion of the address space where the .so was loaded.  Even if you're calling the same function inside helper.a, you're calling two different 'instances' of that function depending on whether the call was made from the .exe or the .so.

Comment: I see. but how could I add the code in libhelper.a to plugin.so at compile time? should I specify something like "gcc -lhelper.a -static" when compiling plugin.so?

Comment: If your library is libhelper.a, then pass -L*dir* -lhelper to gcc when compiling plugin.so, where *dir* is the path to libhelper.a.  No need to specify -static, that's used when you're creating a static library.

Comment: This answer is correct only under limited conditions, which aren't stated.

Answer (score 0):

i think this question is the same as yours. [How to force symbols from a static library to be included in a shared library build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253801/how-to-force-symbols-from-a-static-library-to-be-included-in-a-shared-library-bu)

The --whole-archive linker option should do this. You'd use it as e.g.

gcc -o libmyshared.so foo.o -lanothersharedlib -Wl,--whole-archive -lmystaticlib

and it works for me.